# How do I save a FBO to the camera roll ios in swift

Tags: ios, opengl-es

How do you save a opengl es FBO to the ios camera roll in swift

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. FBOs are (metaphorically speaking) frames holding canvas (render attachments) on a scaffolding. There is no such thing as a "camera" in OpenGL, but just a chain of transformations, which make things show up at the right place of the "canvas". Also there is no such thing as models or a scene in OpenGL. There are just point, lines and triangles, which have zero relationship with each other, as far as OpenGL is concerned (and unless we're ignoring edge information used in tesselation shaders).

Comment: @datenwolf he is asking how to save rendered target from FBO to a file and move it to "Camera Roll" which is Gallery for iOS devices. The question can be splitter into getting the FBO from GPU to CPU and then saving file to Camera Roll

Comment: @codetiger: Thank you. With that additional bit of information the question makes sense.